# Minimum and Maximums involving Partial Derivatives

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

Hi all. I was wondering if someone could help me learn to approach this problem.

the partial derivatives I have are:

$f_x=4x-8$

$f_y=2y$

$f_{xy} = 0.$

How does the constraint affect the problem? Are my partial derivatives correct?

Comment: Your partial derivatives are correct, and you can use these to find the critical point(s) in the interior of the region.  Then you need to look at the values of the function on the boundary separately.

Comment: Is 2,0 = -8 the interior point?

Comment: See Mary Star's answer for analysis of what happens at this critical point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the theorem:

Let $f$ be a function with two variables with continuous second order partial derivatives $f_{xx}, f_{yy}, f_{xy}$ at a critical point $(a,b)$ 
$$D=f_{xx}(a,b)f_{yy}(a,b)-f_{xy}^2(a,b)$$

- If $D > 0$ and $f_{xx}(a,b) > 0$, then $f$ has a relative minimum at $(a,b)$.
- If $D > 0$ and $f_{xx}(a,b) < 0$, then $f$ has a relative maximum at $(a,b)$.

$$f_x=4x-8 \Rightarrow f_{xx}=4, \\ f_y=2y \Rightarrow f_{yy}=2, \\ f_{xy}=0$$

The critical points satisfy the equations $f_x(x,y)=0$ and $f_y(x,y)=0$ simultaneously.

Therefore, $f_x=4x-8 =0 \Rightarrow x=2$ and $f_y=2y=0 \Rightarrow y=0$

So the critical point $(a,b)$ is $(2,0)$.

This point satisfies the contraint: $2^2+0^2=4 \leq 9$.

$$D=f_{xx}(2,0)f_{yy}(2,0)-f_{xy}^2(2,0)=4 \cdot 2=8>0$$

Since $D>0$ and $f_{xx}(2,0)>0$ the function $f$ has a local minimum at $(2,0)$, which is equal to $f(2,0)=-8$.

**EDIT:**

The problem $$\max 2x^2-8x+y^2 \\ x^2+y^2 -9\leq 0$$ is a nonlinear programming problem.

So we can use the following:

$$\max f(X) \\ g_i(X) \leq 0, \ \ \ i=1, \dots, p $$

($X$ is a vector: $X=(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$)

If there are $X^* \in \mathbb{R}^n, \mu \in \mathbb{R}^p$ such that 
$$ \mu_k \geq 0 , k =1,2, \dots, p \\ \frac{\partial{f(X^*)}}{\partial{X_j}}-\sum_{k=1}^p \mu_k \frac{\partial{g_k(X^*)}}{\partial{X_j}}=0, j=1,2, \dots , n \\ \mu_k g_k(X^*) =0, k=1,2, \dots, p \\ g_k(X^*) \leq 0, k=1,2, \dots, p$$ 
then $X^*$ is the solution of the problem, that means that it is the maximum of $f$ subject to the constraint $g(X) \leq 0$.

Is this case the vector $X$ is $(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-9$

$n=2$, $p=1$

So, we have the following:

$$ \mu_1 \geq 0  \ \ \ (1) \\ 4x-8- \mu_12x=0 \ \ \ (2) \\ 2y-\mu_1 2y=0 \ \ \ (3) \\ \mu_1 (x^2+y^2-9) =0 \ \ \ (4) \\ x^2+y^2-9 \leq 0 \ \ \ (5) $$

$(3) \Rightarrow 2y(1- \mu_1)=0 \Rightarrow y=0 \text{ or } \mu_1=1$

- $\mu_1=1:$

$(2) \Rightarrow 4x-8-2x=0 \Rightarrow 2x=8 \Rightarrow x=4$

$(4) \Rightarrow 16+y^2-9 =0 \Rightarrow y^2=-5$ That cannot be true.

Therefore, it should be $y=0$.

- $y=0:$

Then relations are as followed:

$$ \mu_1 \geq 0  \ \ \ (1) \\ 4x-8- \mu_12x=0 \ \ \ (2) \\ \mu_1 (x^2-9) =0 \ \ \ (4) \\ x^2-9 \leq 0 \ \ \ (5) $$

$(4) \Rightarrow \mu_1=0 \text{ or } x= \pm 3$

If $\mu_1=0:$

$(2) \Rightarrow 4x-8=0 \Rightarrow x=2$

$(5) \Rightarrow 4-9 =-5 \leq 0\checkmark$

So, since all the $5$ relations are satisfied $(2,0)$ is a point of possible maximum. The value of $f$ at this point is $f(2,0)=-8$.

If $x=3:$

$(2) \Rightarrow 12-8- \mu_1 6=0 \Rightarrow 6 \mu_1=4 \Rightarrow \mu_1=\frac{2}{3}$

So, since all the $5$ relations are satisfied $(3,0)$ is also a point of possible maximum. The value of $f$ at this point is $f(3,0)=-6$.

Since $-6>-8$ the previous one $f(2,0)$ is not the maximum.

If $x=-3:$

$(2) \Rightarrow -12-8+ \mu_1 6= \Rightarrow 6 \mu_1=20 \Rightarrow \mu_1=\frac{10}{3}$

So, since all the $5$ relations are satisfied $(-3,0)$ is also a point of possible maximum. The value of $f$ at this point is $f(-3,0)=42$.

Since $42>-6$ the previous one $f(3,0)$ is not the maximum.

So, we conclude that the function $f$ achieves its maximum at the pooint $(-3, 0)$, which is equal to $f(-3,0)=42$.

Comment: (I think you also need to check the values of the function on the circle $x^2+y^2=9$, since a maximum or minimum could occur there.)

Comment: I think there may be a maximum also?

Comment: I edited my post..